# What's wrong with my class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a class for animals, and set `Dog()` to print what characteristics a dog would have, but i'm not very sure what to do, or where i've gone wrong? 
 I've only been writing classes for about a half hour so that's why i'm not very good, thanks in advance! Here is my code!

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, animal, name, bark):
        self.animal = animal
        self.name = name
        self.bark = bark
    def Dog(self):
        self.bark = 'Woof!'
        self.animal = 'dog'
        print('A {} goes {}'.format(self.animal, self.bark))

d1 = Animal()
print(d1.dog())
```

Comment: What output do you get, and what did you expect?

Comment: Expected 'A dog goes Woof!'

Comment: Got a type error `TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'animal', 'name', and 'bark'`

Comment: Can I ask what you're using to learn classes?

Comment: this guy http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gGMwx9JHpWc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why your `Animal`-class has a `Dog`-method. Didn't you want to learn inheritance with this one? It looks like a typical task for programming newbies. Maybe something like this

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, animal, name, bark):
        self.animal = animal
        self.name = name
        self.bark = bark

    def say(self):
        print('A {} goes {}'.format(self.animal, self.bark))

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self, "dog", "", "Woof!")

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self, "cat", "", "Miao!")        


d1 = Dog()
d1.say()

c1 = Cat()
c1.say()
```

will give you

```
A dog goes Woof!
A cat goes Miao!
```

Answer (score 4):

- Your `Animal()` class requires 3 arguments to initialize, you passed in none.
- You named the method `.Dog()` (with capital `D`) but try to call `.dog()` (all lowercase).

Both are simple to correct:

```
d1 = Animal('dog', 'Fido', 'woof!')
d1.Dog()
```

You do not *have* to name attributes for your class as parameters to the `__init__` function either. The `Dog()` method overrides any attributes set, for example, so why ask them to be set in `__init__` in the first place?